# Gocolly scraping only certain links

Tags: go, go-colly

While scraping this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go/blob/main/README.md) , i just want to scrape library links, but the code I wrote extracts all the links, I couldn't manage to filter it. (I'm parsing the urls for later use in github api

> [http://api.github.com/repos/[username]/[reponame]](http://api.github.com/repos/%5Busername%5D/%5Breponame%5D)

, so I only need the path parts , but I don't want to parse the links that don't work for me to avoid unnecessary operations, so I only need library links)

```
type repo struct {
Link string `json:"link"`
Name string `json:"name"`
```

}

```
allRepos := make([]repo, 0)
collector := colly.NewCollector(
    colly.AllowedDomains("github.com"))

collector.OnHTML("ul", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {

    r := repo{}
    r.Link = e.ChildAttr("a", "href")
    url, _ := url.Parse(r.Link)

    repos := repo{
        Link: url.Path,
    }
    allRepos = append(allRepos, repos)
})

collector.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
})
// Sends HTTP requests to the server
collector.Visit("https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go/blob/main/README.md")

fmt.Println(allRepos)
enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.SetIndent("", "\t")
//githubApi := "https://api.github.com/repos"
for _, repos := range allRepos {
    fmt.Println(repos.Link)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage what you need. Let me share with you my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
)

type Repo struct {
    Link string `json:"link"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    repos := []Repo{}
    c := colly.NewCollector(colly.AllowedDomains(
        "github.com",
    ))

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        r.Headers.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
    })

    c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        fmt.Println("Response Code:", r.StatusCode)
    })

    // to get the "a" tag
    c.OnHTML("article>ul>li", func(h *colly.HTMLElement) {
        listItem := h.DOM
        for _, v := range listItem.Nodes {
            for _, a := range v.FirstChild.Attr {
                if a.Key == "href" && strings.Contains(a.Val, "github.com") {
                    repos = append(repos, Repo{Link: a.Val, Name: v.FirstChild.FirstChild.Data})
                }
            }
        }
    })

    c.Visit("https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go/blob/main/README.md")

    for _, v := range repos {
        fmt.Printf("%v\t%v\n", v.Name, v.Link)
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet you can see how I set up the callbacks to scrape the GitHub repo.
The relevant changes were done in the `OnHTML` method. Here, we used a jQuery selector to get all of the `li` below the `article` and `ul` tags. Then, you've to range over the underlying nodes and get the `FirstChild` that will always be an `a` tag. You've to grab the `href` attribute and append it to the `repos` variable that you just found.

> **Note**: as you were concerned only with GitHub repos, I added a clause in the `if` construct in order to exclude the not-relevant links. If you plan to remove this link, pay attention to the links as you've to deal also the page's navigation links such as `page#section-1`.

I hope that this solves your issue. Let me know or maybe share your solution if you've already found another one by yourself!

Comment: Hi @Enes Alp Aslan, does this solve your issue?